# SQL: How to Group by Custom Year

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by

For simplicities sake, I'll make up a similar example to what I have:

Let's say a db has a table of orders with an OrderDate field and a Company field. Then there's a table of Companies and each record has a YearEndingDate (which signifies that the year ends on that date each year, e.g. 6/6).

I need to add up all of the orders for each year.

I assume it would have to be something like this but I can't quite figure it out:

```
SELECT SUM(orderValue),
CASE WHEN orderDate <= YearEndingDate THEN DatePart(year, orderDate)
CASE WHEN orderDate > YearEndingDate THEN DatePart(year, orderDate) + 1
END as Year
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Company ON Company.companyID = Order.companyID
GROUP By Company, Year
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should specify what DBMS you are using.

Comment: I was intentionally leaving this out because I have to do it in both a local SQLite db and a central SqlServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what RDMS you are using but this should do the trick. The datepart and dateadd stuff are tsql specific but I'd assume you'd have access to similar functions on whatever platform you are using. The case in the where determines which year value to use.

Answer:

```
select c.companyid
      ,yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,1,o.orderdate))) as yearending
      ,sum(ordervalue) as numberoforders
  from @orders o
       join @companies c
         on o.companyid = c.companyid
 where orderdate between case when (cast(yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate)) as datetime) >= o.orderdate)
                         then yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,-1,o.orderdate)))
                         else yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate))
                          end
                     and 
                         case when (cast(yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate)) as datetime) >= o.orderdate)
                         then yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate))
                         else yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,1,o.orderdate)))
                          end
 group by c.companyid, o.orderdate, yearendingdate
```

Code to figure out problem:

```
declare @orders table (OrderDate datetime
                      ,CompanyID varchar(20)
                      ,OrderValue int)

insert into @orders
values (getdate(),'MS',2)

insert into @orders
values (DateAdd(year, -1, getdate()),'MS',3)

insert into @orders
values (DateAdd(year, -1, getdate()),'MS',1)

insert into @orders
values (DateAdd(year, 1, getdate()),'MS',4)

insert into @orders
values (DateAdd(year, 1, getdate()),'Blizzard',2)

insert into @orders
values (getdate(),'MS',11)

declare @companies table (CompanyID varchar(20)
                         ,YearEndingDate varchar(20))

insert into @companies
values ('MS', '05/6')

insert into @companies
values ('Blizzard', '07/01')

select c.companyid
      ,o.orderdate
      ,yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate)) as sameyear
      ,yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,1,o.orderdate))) as plusyear
      ,yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,-1,o.orderdate))) as minusyear
  from @orders o
       join @companies c
         on o.companyid = c.companyid

select c.companyid
      ,yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,1,o.orderdate))) as yearending
      ,sum(ordervalue) as numberoforders
  from @orders o
       join @companies c
         on o.companyid = c.companyid
 where orderdate between case when (cast(yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate)) as datetime) >= o.orderdate)
                         then yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,-1,o.orderdate)))
                         else yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate))
                          end
                     and 
                         case when (cast(yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate)) as datetime) >= o.orderdate)
                         then yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, o.orderdate))
                         else yearendingdate + '/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yy, dateadd(yy,1,o.orderdate)))
                          end
 group by c.companyid, o.orderdate, yearendingdate
```

Comment: There's several iterations of this answer because I walked away from it for an hour and realized I had a problem where orderdates existing prior to a year ending date would have gotten thrown out. I added the case statement to account for that issue.

Finally, the table variables are there so that I could test the solution.